# Copy files from one folder to another using ssh2 in node js

Tags: node.js, express, ssh

Hi I am trying to copy files from ssh client I am able to check no. of files in that path but if I am trying to createReadStream for that getting ***No such file*** error.

```
const conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Connection :: ready');

        const sourceFolder = '/home/path/logs/';
        const destinationFolder = '/home/path/folder/';
        const localFolderPath = './downloaded-files/';

        fs.mkdirSync(localFolderPath, { recursive: true });

        conn.sftp((err, sftp) => {
            if (err) {
                conn.end();
                return res.status(500).send('Error connecting to SFTP');
            }

            sftp.readdir(sourceFolder, (err, files) => {
                if (err) {
                    conn.end();
                    return res.status(500).send('Error reading directory');
                }

                let filesProcessed = 0;

                // console.dir(files) // 2;

                files.forEach((file) => {

                    const remoteFilePath = path.join(sourceFolder, file.filename);
                    const localFilePath = path.join(localFolderPath, file.filename);                      

                    const remoteReadStream = sftp.createReadStream(remoteFilePath);
                    const localWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(localFilePath);

                    remoteReadStream.on('error', (err) => {
                        console.error(`Error reading remote file "${remoteFilePath}":`, err);
                        console.log(filesProcessed);
                        filesProcessed++;
                        console.log(filesProcessed,files.length);
                        if (filesProcessed === files.length) {
                            console.log("error in remoteReadStream");
                            conn.end();
                            res.status(200).send('All files downloaded');
                        }
                    });

                    localWriteStream.on('error', (err) => {
                        console.error('Error reading remote file:', err);
                        filesProcessed++;
                        if (filesProcessed === files.length) {
                            console.log("error in localWriteStream");
                            conn.end();
                            res.status(200).send('All files downloaded');
                        }
                    });

                    remoteReadStream.pipe(localWriteStream);

                    localWriteStream.on('finish', () => {
                        filesProcessed++;
                        if (filesProcessed === files.length) {
                            console.log("finish");
                            conn.end();
                            res.status(200).send('All files downloaded');
                        }
                    });


                });                    
            });
        });


    }).connect({
        host: 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx',
        port: 22,
        username: "xxxx",
        password: "xxxx",
    });
```

[image: error]

I am trying to copy all files from one folder to another I am able to read no.of files inside that folder but if I try to read the file I am getting no such file issue . Please help me with the issue . Thanks in advance